# How do you assign shell variables inside of a sh -c "..." command?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

When you execute

```
jeremy@home:/$DOG=happy; echo $DOG;
```

you get the output

```
happy
```

However, when you execute
    jeremy@home:/$sh -c "DOG=happy; echo $DOG;"

or even

```
jeremy@home:/$sh -c "DOG=happy; echo "$DOG";"
```

or

```
jeremy@home:/$sh -c "DOG=happy; echo \"$DOG\";"
```

or

```
jeremy@home:/$sh -c "DOG=happy; echo '$DOG';"
```

you get only a blank line.  How is this so?  How can I actually set a variable from inside a sh -c command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the dollar sign (`\$`).

```
> sh -c "DOG=happy; echo \$DOG;"
happy
```

Another option is to use single quotes instead of double quotes - variables aren't evaluated inside of single quotes, so the `$DOG` will be passed through to `sh` for evaluation.

```
> sh -c 'DOG=happy; echo $DOG'
happy
```

However, if you need to both substitute in variables before passing to `sh`, and also pass certain variables through, it's usually easiest to just escape the ones you do want to pass through.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, I was trying to execute it as part of a find command, like find . -exec sh -c "...";, So I think I did want to pass through the variable {}, although I'm not sure if that is done by a different mechanism.

Comment: `{}` is only a variable to `find`.

Answer (score 5):

The good command is:

```
sh -c 'DOG=happy; echo $DOG;'
```

or you can just escape the '$' sign

```
sh -c "DOG=happy; echo \$DOG;"
```